# How to use Org mode for i3/sway config files

Tags: doom, literate-programming, tangle

I use the `swaywm`. It's similar to `i3`. The Emacs distribution I use is `doom-emacs`
I recently learnt about literate config files. But how make literate configs for something like this. The text is not in any particular programming language. I tried to use `conf` for tangling code blocks. But that throws up errors and emacs crashes. Here's a sample of the code I'm talking about https://github.com/swaywm/sway/blob/master/config.in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just type `in` where you'd mention the language of the source block.

This should work:

```
#+begin_src in :tangle yes
Code goes here
#+end_src
```

If your file is named `config.org`, this will tangle to `config.in`.

Not sure whether this is good practice, but you could also use something generic like `sh`, and then provide a filename to tangle to:

```
#+begin_src sh :tangle config.in
Code goes here
#+end_src
```

Comment: yep `in` works just fine. but `sway` needs the config file to be named `config` and not `config.in`. When I try to do that `emacs` crashes again.

Comment: hey an update! when I don't put any programming language, it doesn't throw up any errors. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great. Strange though, because Org-mode documentation indicates that the language is a required element of the source block. The most important part for your usecase is setting the argument after `:tangle`, which should be the filename you want (so without any file extension).

Comment: What is `in`? Just a placeholder for an undefined babel language? Could I use `foo` instead? Or does `in` have some special meaning?

Comment: I suggested `in`, a placeholder indeed, because doing so will ensure the tangled file has `.in` as extension. The better solution would be to provide a filename via `:tangle`.